# Disable click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#likebtn1').click(function(){
    $.post("postlike.php",
    {img1link: img1}
);
    $(this).click(false);
});
```

When the div `likebtn1` is clicked, it needs post some data to a PHP file so that it can update a table. I only want it to be allowed to be clicked once (to prevent multiple clicks by 1 person). For some reason the above code isn't working. If I click lots of times, it still keeps updating the table.

Edit: When the user clicks another div the click needs to be re-enabled.

Comment: When re-enabled , same contents of original `click` event ?, or does handler function body change ?

Comment: Yes the click event stays the same after it's re-enabled by clicking on a different div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like so:

```
function myFunction() {
    $('#likebtn1').one('click', function () {
        $.post("postlike.php", {
            img1link: img1
        });
    });
}

myFunction(); // run on document.ready

$('#myOtherButton').click(function() {
    myFunction(); // re-enable the other button
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$('#likebtn1').one(function(){})`

**UPDATE**

You can also use `$('#likebtn1').bind('click')` and `$('#likebtn1').unbind('click')` events if you need to disable `click` first and later enable it again.

Comment: When the user clicks another div the click needs to be re-enabled. Is that possible with this?

Comment: That is the answer for binding, and he wants to use on. See my answer.

Comment: unbind worked to disable the click, but I put bind in the click function for the other div but it won't post anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
var _clicked = false;

var _click = function(e) {
  $.post("postlike.php",{img1link: img1});
  _clicked = true;
};

$("#likebtn1").one("click", _click);

if (_clicked) {
  $("#anotherDiv").on("click", _click);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change pointer-events in css for this div

```
.addclass{
   pointer-events: none;
}

$('#likebtn1').click(function(){
    $.post("postlike.php",
    {img1link: img1},
    function(){
    $(this).addClass('addclass');
    }
);
});
```

in another div click event

```
 $('#likebtn1').removeClass('addclass');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it more than once, using the on handler:

```
    $('#likebtn1').click(function(){
    $.post("postlike.php",
    {img1link: img1}
);
    $(this).off('click');
});
```

This has benefits over event binding, because `off` accepts a callback:

```
$(this).off('click', function () {});
```

Comment: Not sure how this makes it repeatable.

Comment: You're removing the click handler. What puts it back for repeat events?

Comment: Using another on handler.